# Adding Material to Cycles Material library in Material Library VX addon

Tags: materials, add-on

I want to add a material to the Cycles material library in the Material Library VX addon. But can't get it to work.

I can create a new category. What is not working is to insert a new material then. I press the add button, the status bar above tells me that the material is added. But it is not.

So what is the trick here? What is the exact procedure to add a material to the Cycles material library in the addon? What do i overlook here?

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work at all. The demo video is 7 years old, I wonder why this still comes with blender...?

Comment: Ah, that's bad news. So it seems the only way is to manually edit the blend files and the categories list in the addon folder then.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. It is possible. But a bit tricky. The filter category has to be off. Then it works. The steps are:

```
Turn filter categories off
Save Blend file with your new material.
Insert selected Material
Select material in the addon list
Switch to the category where you want to insert it.
Click at arrow button
Turn on filter categories
Refresh Library by clicking at the Filter Category button.
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it still working? I downloaded the latest official 2.79 version and stopped working. It used to work fine without having to go thru all your steps, but now even with your steps, it doesn't work.

Comment: I manage to solve the same problem. Mine was created due to the fact that I had created a category called "colors", "Colors", "COLORS", and this was creating a conflict, so I deleted this category from the blender.app/Contents/Resources/2.79/scripts/addons/materials_library_vx => and the problem was solved. So, now by just clicking on the + sign, the material gets added to the library. No more clicks needed. Just save the file first, as usual.